# Reducer Class not working as expected in Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I tried to implement simple group by in Mapreduce.

My Input file given below:

```
7369,SMITH,CLERK,800,20
7499,ALLEN,SALESMAN,1600,30
7521,WARD,SALESMAN,1250,30
7566,JONES,MANAGER,2975,20
7654,MARTIN,SALESMAN,1250,30
7698,BLAKE,MANAGER,2850,30
7782,CLARK,MANAGER,2450,10
7788,SCOTT,ANALYST,3000,20
7839,KING,PRESIDENT,5000,10
7844,TURNER,SALESMAN,1500,30
7876,ADAMS,CLERK,1100,20
7900,JAMES,CLERK,950,30
7902,FORD,ANALYST,3000,20
7934,MILLER,CLERK,1300,10
```

My Mapper Class:

```
public class Groupmapper extends Mapper<Object,Text,IntWritable,IntWritable> {
    @Override
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String line = value.toString();
        String[] parts=line.split(",");
        String token1=parts[3];
        String token2=parts[4];
        int deptno=Integer.parseInt(token2);
        int sal=Integer.parseInt(token1);
        context.write(new IntWritable(deptno),new IntWritable(sal));
    }    
}
```

Reducer Class:

```
public class Groupreducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable> {
    IntWritable result=new IntWritable();
    public void Reduce(IntWritable key,Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        int sum=0;
        for(IntWritable val:values){
            sum+=val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key,result);
    }
}
```

Driver Class:

```
public class Group {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Configuration conf=new Configuration();
        Job job=Job.getInstance(conf,"Group");
        job.setJarByClass(Group.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Groupmapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(Groupreducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Groupreducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);         
    }
}
```

Expected output should be:

```
10      8750
20      10875
30      9400
```

But It prints output given below. It didn't aggregate the values.
It works like identity reducer.

```
10      1300
10      5000
10      2450
20      1100
20      3000
20      800
20      2975
20      3000
30      1500
30      1600
30      2850
30      1250
30      1250
30      950
```

Reducer function not working properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does look like the reduce isn't being used. Thus taking a closer look at your reducer would be the next step in debug.

If you add an `@Override` to your reduce method (as you do on your map method) you'll see that that you get an `Method does not override method from its superclass` error. This means that hadoop won't be using your reduce method, and will be using the default identity implementation.

The problem is that you have:

`public void Reduce(IntWritable key,Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)`

and it should be:

`public void reduce(IntWritable key,Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)`

The only difference being the name of the method should start with a lowercase `r`.